# Returning Promises within Asynchronous Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

In short my questions are:

1. If using bluebird should inherently be "promisifying" things?
2. Under these cases should I just callan explicit Promise.(resolve|reject)
   within the sub Asynchronous function, and attach a return to it, like the format for the 2nd function?
3. I may be understanding the control flow of the promises incorrectly, when everything is good within the fs.readFile things will go as they should, is the async code not simulating a return when it meets that reject?
4. What happens to the running Async Function after the Promise has been rejected? Does it just return the result to that awaiting Promise, and then the Async code is left hanging around, doing whatever it wants until compltion?

   - Is it basically just treating the whole thing like one big generator, without a yield telling it to stop executing at this point?
5. I have one last question, but searching it up would likely answer it. Is my promise chain methodology proper? I've used them before, and every once in a while I run into the unhandled rejection issue. I am setting up a catch block, and doing so in favor of running with format .then((res)=>{...}, (rej)=>{...}) as its an antiPattern as stated by the PromisesA+ conventions.

I've been running into this recently with regards to my using Promises, and i somewhat understand the logic behind the behavior stated, but some parts are not fully clicking.

The issue is that I have some code that's calling up an asynchronous function, for the sake of relating this to most users of Node using fs.readFile. When executing the code below, I keep running into situations under which the Promise is rejecting, or getting into it's reject clause, but the rest of the function is being executed.

I get the reason why the second iteration works, due to the returns enforcing the native control flow, but I also think of the Promise wrapper around the function call as instating it's own flow control, and once it's resolve/reject function is triggered, the function is terminated. This does not seem to be the case, as the function will reject, and fall through into it's resolve statement. Breaking anything else that pops up with it. The same behavior is seen under other sub-functions , i.e. running request that fails, and other async functions. I am unsure if it will also affect Synchronous code as well.

**NOTE**

The Below Snippet will not run outside of NodeJs, I don't yet know how to deal with it in JSFiddle, and the required fs module is, I believe, node specific.

```
/*
 Seemingly bypassing my Promise's reject statements
 This does not only happen with fs, but with other none natively promise based sub
 libraries.
 Is it because I am not inherrently promisifying things, should I just return a Promise.resolve within the sub Asynchronous function, and attach a return to it, like the format for the 2nd function?

I may be understanding the control flow of the promises incorrectly, when everything is good within the fs.readFile things will go as they should, since the last thing being done is basically resolving, and the control flow is implicitly acting like that native flow.
 */
const Promise = require('bluebird'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  fName = './tmpFs.txt';

const retPromExample = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(fName, (err, fd) => {
      if (err) {
        // The if condition is applied and satisfied
        console.log("\nI got in here, and I know I've failed\n");
        reject(err)
      }
      // It still gets here, even though err is clearly not null, if the file does not exist
      console.log("I'm outside the if(err) with ", err);
      // Do something with the file, try and JSON.parse it, and fd is undefined.
      resolve("What I wanted to do was done. Resolving\n")
    })
  })
};

const retPromExample_deux = () => {
  // On the rejection getting an unhandled rejection error as well. Am I following the syntax for this correctly?
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    return fs.readFile(fName, (err, fd) => {
      if (err) {
        // The if condition is applied and satisfied
        return Promise.reject("Part Deux; I got in here, and I know I've failed %s \n", err)
      }
      // Under this case an explicit return is given, it should not reach here. If the file does not exist. Err should be null.
      console.log("I'm outside the if(err) with ", err);
      // Base control Flow states that this should not fail in any manner.
      return Promise.resolve("What I wanted to do was done. Resolving")
    })
  })
};

// Toggle which is run with node FSTest.js 1 or Nothing.
if (process.argv.find(val => val === '1'))
  retPromExample()
  .then(val => console.log(val))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
else
  retPromExample_deux()
  .then(val => console.log(val))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: Your `retPromExample` is mostly right. `retPromExample_deux` is not. :-) Details below.

> 1. If using bluebird should inherently be "promisifying" things?

No. Only actually using them uses them.

> 2. Under these cases should I just callan explicit Promise.(resolve|reject) within the sub Asynchronous function, and attach a return to it, like the format for the 2nd function?

No (more later).

> 3. I may be understanding the control flow of the promises incorrectly, when everything is good within the `fs.readFile` things will go as they should, is the async code not simulating a return when it meets that `reject`?

If everything is going well, you shouldn't reach the `reject` (more below).

It's not simulating a return, it's settling the promise that you've already returned.

> 4. What happens to the running Async Function after the Promise has been rejected?

In your case, by the time the promise is being resolved/rejected (collectively, "settled"), the function that started the asynchronous process (`readFile`) has long since ended, and the underlying asynchronous I/O process is also completed by then because you're doing it from the completion callback.

> 5. ...Is my promise chain methodology proper? I've used them before, and every once in a while I run into the unhandled rejection issue. I am setting up a catch block, and doing so in favor of running with format .then((res)=>{...}, (rej)=>{...}) as its an antiPattern as stated by the PromisesA+ conventions.

The promise chains at the end of your question are just fine. I'm not aware of using the second argument to `then` being any kind of anti-pattern, but personally I do prefer using `catch`, as much for formatting reasons as anything else.

You won't get "unhandled rejection" errors from the chains you've shown, because you're always handling rejections. You **will** get "unhandled rejection" errors from `retPromExample_deux`, because the promises you create with `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject` are never consumed anywhere, which means the rejection from `Promise.reject` goes unhandled. (Which is one of the reasons `retPromExample_deux` is incorrect.)

---

Re your `retPromExample`: That's very nearly how you use a promise with a non-promise asynchronous callback API like `readFile`, except you want an `else` that you're missing:

```
const retPromExample = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(fName, (err, fd) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("\nI got in here, and I know I've failed %s\n", err);
        reject(err)
      } else {                                 // <==== *** Here ***
        console.log("I'm outside the if(err) with ", err);
        resolve("What I wanted to do was done. Resolving\n")
      }
    })
  })
};
```

If there was an error and you `reject` the promise, you don't then want to continue on to your success logic and call `resolve` (although calling `resolve` on a settled promise is a no-op).

Your `retPromExample_deux` is not correct because it's **returning** values from the promise executor (the function you pass into `new Promise`) and from the `readFile` callback. Neither the `Promise` constructor nor `readFile` makes any use of those return values, at all. The promise you're returning will never be settled.

Comment: For question 4. Although the promise handler has accepted the resolution, of it's spawn (Resolution may be the wrong word here...) The function that has called it will continue executing everything else within it's code block, unless stinted with the else condition? You'd stated under my case it would not prove any difficulties or break things, but what cases should I look out for in the future to not break the full control of the program, and under those cases is that were an explicit generator function, or coroutine within bluebird, would come to play? --Will add these questions to main ^^

Comment: @L.P.: Right. Calling `resolve` or `reject` is just that: A function call, nothing more special than that. Which means that execution of the function making those calls continues, which is why I added the `else` to separate your two branches there (success and failure). Sometimes you want to resolve the promise then go on to do something else afterward, which is fine. So just remember that the calls only set the promise state, they don't terminate the function you call them from.

Comment: @L.P.: I've updated the answer for question #5. Ideally, Stack Overflow questions aren't supposed to be moving targets. :-)

Comment: That clears a lot of the questions up. I remembered that last point you'd made due to another question which I updated, and mangled the initial interpretation of, so will keep things within the state they are in now. The main thing that you'd pointed out due to the created and thus returned Promises does fully state the behavior I had seen. moving away from that return Promise.resolve within a new Promise is definitely a plus on knowledge base. I've been doing that a lot, mostly not within Promises, but normal functions that I want to incite Promise handling in, but knowing this helps.

Comment: I now have a bunch of random code snippets to revise, which will likely mean completely rewriting most of it lol(Masking the anguish as I'm crying in a corner due to this...). I'll fully look over that guide though, need to master promises, and Generators. Even though I've used Generators a lot in Python, the way to use them within JS feels intensely foreign.

Comment: @L.P.: If you're doing a lot of rewriting *anyway*, look at some of the "promisifying" libraries out there for node. What they do is make it easy to get a version of an API (say, the `fs` module) that uses promises instead of the standard Node callback pattern. [`promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify), for instance, lets you describe the API declaratively, then you promisify the result of a `require` call, and use the promise-enabled API.

Comment: I've used Promisification within Bluebird and so far it's not bad, I tend to try and lean as little towards the use of external resources if possible to achieve the intended functionality with native modules. Even in using bluebird, I've noticed a lot of the things they employ can be done natively. I would not use my native hackjobs in production code of any sort, most of the time, since there are likely to be optimizations done to the libraries that I'd rather take advantage of.

Comment: @L.P.: Bluebird predates JavaScript's built-in promises by some time and is part of the prior art that inspired them.